# The assignment operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operators

I have this simple code on the JavaScript.

```js
var a = 10;
var b = 20;

a=a+b-(b=a);

document.write("a = " + a + "</br> b = " + b);
```

Can somebody explain me, how did these variables change the values and how is the assignment operator works in this case ? I think, that on the first step the variable b is rewrote by number from a: (b=a).

Comment: What specifically are you asking about? Have you looked up how assignment operators work? Is JS your first language, or do you have knowledge of other languages?

Comment: Assignment operator returns the assigned value,  so `b=a` returns `10`.

Comment: a is getting assigned the value of a + b minus the new value of b that was just assigned the value of a... I think that answer is equally as clear as the question ;)

Comment: I believe MDN's page on Operator Precedence contains all the information needed to figure this one out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: @shabs The parenthesis make the precedence clear already. What the page doesn't mention is evaluation order.

Comment: @Bergi the first sentence of the page is "Operator precedence determines the order in which operators are evaluated." -- can you help me understand what im missing?

Comment: @shabs Oh, that sentence is wrong. Operator precedence is about parsing into a syntax tree and which is the operand of which, not about evaluation order (though an *arithmetic* operator has to evaluate all its operands before being processed itself, of course). I'll fix MDN.

Comment: [ -- deleted -- ]

Comment: My suggestion is to never write code like this. It won't pass the linter.

Answer (score 2):

It's evaluated outside-in, from left to right, as usually.
The assignment expression returns the assigned value.

```
a = a + b - (b = a);    // a=10 b=20
a = 10 + b -( b = a);   // a=10 b=20
a = 10 + 20 - (b = a);  // a=10 b=20
a = 30 - (b = a);       // a=10 b=20
a = 30 - (b = 10);      // a=10 b=20
a = 30 - (10);          // a=10 b=10
a = 30 - 10;            // a=10 b=10
a = 20;                 // a=10 b=10
20;                     // a=20 b=10
```

Comment: `a=10+20-(b= a); // a=10 b=20`
`a=  30 - (b= a); // a=10 b=20`

I thought that the first expression will be evaluated in brackets, but in this example, the first step is `10+20`.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, that was exactly your misconception. If `(b=a)` would have been evaluated before `a+b`, you wouldn't get the result you're actually getting.

Comment: @Alexander The first expression that is evaluated is the outer assignment, which then has to evaluate the `-` operation, which then has to evaluate its left operand (the sum) and after that its right operand (the inner assignment). Outside-in, left-to-right.

Answer (score 1):

Simple explanations below.

1 . We are assigning our initial values:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 20;
```

2 . Here we're saying `a is equal to 10+20 - (10)`. Therefore `a` is now equal to `20` and `b` is equal to `10` as it was assigned to be `a` **before** we assigned `a`'s new value.

```
a=a+b-(b=a);
```

3 . Result:

```js
var a = 10;
var b = 20;

a = a + b - (b = a);

console.log("a = " + a); // a = 20
console.log("b = " + b); // b = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's look closely at this: a = a + b - (b = a);

Let's replace variables with values
a = (10 + 20) - (10)

This is because B == 20 until redefined at the end of the expression.